# Conditioning on $X$ equal to premultiplying by $X'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, regression

I am coming across similar thing in many problems in econometrics and I have not been able to figure out whether it is some general notion or only a "coincidence".

To take two examples:

Deriving Ordinary Least Squares estimator
$$Y = X\beta + \epsilon\\ E(Y\mid X) = E(X\beta\mid X) + E(\epsilon\mid X) \\ X'Y = X'X\hat{\beta}$$
The last term on the second row is by assumption zero.

Deriving Instrumental Variables estimator
$$Y = X\beta + \epsilon\\ E(Y\mid Z) = E(X\beta\mid Z) + E(\epsilon\mid Z) \\ Z'Y = Z'X\hat{\beta}$$
Again, the last term on the second row is by assumption zero.

So, my question is: How firm is the relationship $E( \cdot \mid X) = X'(\cdot)$? How is it connected to linear algebra? Thx.

Comment: How are you finding anywhere in what you've written anything that can be expessed as $E(\cdot\mid X)=X'(\cdot)$?  In the ordinary-least-squares example, you have $E(Y\mid X)=X\beta$.  In the instrumental-variables example, you have $E(Y\mid Z)=E(X\beta\mid Z)$, which is probably also just $X\beta$.  The expression you've got after each of those, involving the transpose, is an equation satisfied by $\hat\beta$, used for finding $\hat\beta$ as a function of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.  You haven't shown that the expected value of anything is an expression with $X'$ as a factor on the left.

Comment: No, $E(Y \mid X) = X \hat{\beta}$ and in IV case it will be $E(Y \mid Z) = X \hat{\beta}_{IV}$. It might be some GMM counterpart. But no matter what in both cases $E(Y|A) = E(X \beta | A)$ is theoretical quantity and the empirical, how you estimate it is $A'Y = A'X \beta$ so I guessed there must be some connection...

Comment: What do you mean by $B'$ in the expression $P(B'A)$?  And what do you mean by $B^{-1}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $X'Y=X'X\hat\beta$ is not how you estimate $X\beta$; it's how you estimate $\beta$.

Comment: At any rate one often sees accounts of this in which $X$ is treated as if it were not random at all, so that one need not and does not condition on $X$ explicitly, and that doesn't change the fact that $\hat\beta$ is found in just that way.

Comment: How would you then go from the theoretical counterpart to the numerical?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you mean from the unobserved expected value of $Y$ to an estimate of it based on the data.  The expected value of $Y$ is $\mathbb E(Y\mid X) = X\beta$.  The least-squares estimate of it is the vector of fitted values $\hat Y = X\hat\beta$ $=X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.  This is not somethings multiplied on the left by $X'$.  It is not true that $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$ $=X'M$ for some matrix $M$.  Notice that $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector whereas $X'M$ would have a number of rows that is smaller than $n$.